# Measuring AC voltages with battery-powered oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, voltage-measurement

I'm wondering if I can view only for few seconds the waveform of a small transformer on my DSO.

It can handle up to 800V according to the manual (transformer outputs are 100V maximum.) From what I know, connecting the DSO to an AC voltage will make the BNC connector live, is this true? If yes, it wouldn't be a problem because I just want to see it for 2 seconds and then disconnect it. Will it blow up my scope?

If you can give me some links to study (for battery-powered oscilloscopes, not the usual ones), will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I once used a battery powered scope to display waveform and measure home mains 220V AC 50Hz and also transformer output of 12/24VAC, for any length of time I liked. The cheapy 80 CNY can use UART to display waveform to my Windows PC.

Comment: You forgot to mention whether or not the secondary of your transformer is isolated from the primary and whether the secondary is connected to ground. Can you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: The cheapy scope I used wqs: UNI-T UT81B LCD Handheld DVM w/USB/ LCD Meter Tester Scope UT-81B - AliExpress US$200
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32277512744.html.  At that time, I found the lamps in my flat flickered heavily. So I used the scope to display the 220VAC 50Hz mains waveform and found AC voltage was not stable and fluctuated by as much a 30V from peak.  The flickering lasted for a couple of days, followed by a total black out of the building.  The repairing guy came fixing told me the main fuse, which is a thick metal bar. had a sort of poor contact before finally blown out. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a battery powered oscilloscope to make measurements is as safe as using a battery powered digital multimeter. Since it is not connected to mains power and is rated to handle the voltage, you should have no problems. As you noted, however, the input BNC connector, which is not grounded, will have voltage with respect to earth ground so you should be careful. In any case you should read the manual for your oscilloscope as it should have information about safety precautions.